# Connect Array to Observable without .interval() in Angular2 Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

Is there a way to do this same functionality without "interval()" part?

I just want to connect the array to an observable, and then just update the array, and the observable to watch that array and react.

If this is good solution, is there a way to implement, and where, the .distinctUntilChanged() into this so that it does not emit new values if the data is the same, then this "interval(10)" will not be the bottleneck.

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xlWSTz8gNfByTnT1REw5?p=preview

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'

@Component({
    selector: 'a-webapp',
    template:`

    <div>
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>

    <button (click)="addToArray()">Add</button> <button (click)="resetArray()">Reset</button>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of latest$ | async">{{ item | json  }}</li>
    </ul>

    {{ data | json }}

    </div>

    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    data = ["one", "two", "three"]
    data$: Rx.Observable<Array<string>>;
    latest$: Rx.Observable<Array<string>>;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.data$ = Rx.Observable.interval(10).concatMap(y => {
            return Rx.Observable.of(this.data)
        })

        this.latest$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(this.data$, (data) => {
            return data.map(d => {
                return d + " is a number"
            })
        })
    }

    addToArray() {
        this.data.push('more numbers')
    }

    resetArray() {
        this.data = ["one", "two", "three"]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> "... and the observable to watch that array and react"

I think it's better to have the observable emitted a new value everytime that array changes

In your case:

```
export class AppComponent {
  data = ["one", "two", "three"];
  data$: Rx.BehaviorSubject<Array<string>>; // or data$: Rx.Subject<Array<string>>
  latest$: Rx.Observable<Array<string>>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject<Array<string>>(this.data);

    this.latest$ = this.data$.map(data => data.map(
      d => "" + d + " is a number"
    ));
  }

  addToArray() {
    this.data.push('more numbers');
    this.data$.next(this.data);
  }

  resetArray() {
    this.data = ["one", "two", "three"];
    this.data$.next(this.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will try this in next 24h. WIll accept the answer if works ;)  Thank you very much!

Comment: Works perfectly! ;))  You are the MAN!